# Help with understanding Apostrophe for worker's or workers'

Tags: grammar, sentence, apostrophe

I am currently writing an essay on Political Economy.

Can I ask what the correct use is for the Apostrophe in this sentence:

1) You could be asking yourself why a worker's democracy is needed?

2) You could be asking yourself why a workers' democracy is needed?

Comment: This question should be on the ELL site.

Comment: Agreed, this is a better fit for ELL.

Comment: What is the ELL site? Link please.

Answer (score -1):

2 is correct. The democracy is that of multiple workers, so workers is plural. Because of that, the apostrophe applies to the plural form and is therefore after the s.

If the democracy was the "property" of a single worker, then it would be that worker's democracy.